# Git file is beyond a symbolic link

Tags: git, symlink

I've ran into an issue wherein Git believes that a file is beyond a symbolic link, and that, thus, it cannot be version controlled,  but it appears to be a real file.

```
[root@r1 h]# stat -f conf/core-site.xml 
  File: "conf/core-site.xml"
    ID: 5c7eb82882a6e866 Namelen: 255     Type: ext2/ext3
Block size: 4096       Fundamental block size: 4096
Blocks: Total: 2735511    Free: 510158     Available: 371202
Inodes: Total: 694960     Free: 597972
```

Additionally, I've tried "readlink" to show the link pointer, but to no avail.

How does Git determine if a file is a symbolic link or not?

Comment: btw this is running in a virtualized environment, not sure that this will make a difference, but i figured id add it as a detail.

Comment: what is the error message? what is the output of git status?

Comment: `stat -f` shows information for the file system, not a particular file.  So that output isn't really relevant.

Comment: Well, my question was indirectly answered below - it turns out that files behind a symlink directory are, themselves, not displayed as symlinks by "stat -f"

Answer (score 6):

`/project/subproject/conf`

If you need to add the `/conf` into the main project and add symlinks for subprojects,

1. Remove conf from subproject and add to the project, and commit changes.

```
$ cp /project/subproject/conf /project
$ rm /project/subproject/conf
$ commit changes
```

2. Then add the symlink and commit

```
$ cd /project/subproject/
$ ln -s ../conf/ conf
$ commit changes
```

Answer (score 1):

Git shows that message for a file /this/is/my/file
in case any of the dirs in the path or the file itself are symlinks.
In your case the file is real, but maybe "conf" dir is a symlink.

Solution:
find the right path for the file and run git add on the real file

Comment: Git must be support the symbolic links, many files maybe far from the repo, but the repo needs their current content, this is an awkward attitude after all those years

Answer (score 0):

I meet the problem when I want to modify a file in node_modules of js project.
Lastly I place an effective file in my js folder and reference it. I remove the original module dependency.